# Is there a fix for jagged, poor-quality text produced by geom_text()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

While adding annotation text to a plot I noticed that `geom_text()` produced unsightly, jagged text, while `annotate()` produced smooth, nice-looking text. Does anyone know why this happens and if there's any way to fix it? I know I could just use `annotate()` here, but there are probably cases where `geom_text()` is preferable, and I'd like to find a fix. Also, `geom_text()` can't be *intended* to give poor-looking text, so either I'm doing something wrong, or I've run into some sort of subtle side effect.

Here's some fake data and the code to produce the graph, plus an image showing the results.

```
library(ggplot2)
age = structure(list(age = c(41L, 40L, 43L, 44L, 40L, 42L, 44L, 45L, 
        44L, 41L, 43L, 40L, 43L, 43L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 43L, 41L)), 
        .Names = "age", row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
ggplot(age, aes(age)) + 
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(40,45,1)) +
  stat_bin(binwidth=1, color="black", fill="blue") +
  geom_text(aes(41, 5.2, 
            label=paste("Average = ", round(mean(age),1))), size=12) +
  annotate("text", x=41, y=4.5, 
           label=paste("Average = ", round(mean(age$age),1)), size=12)
```

[image]

Comment: Using structure is fine, but don't forget to assign: ````age=structure````. I have edited your example.

Comment: My fix is that I generate all the important elements in `ggplot`, then `ggsave(file="plot.eps")` and edit that with Adobe Illustrator or some other vector graphics program for publication quality figures.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`geom_text`, despite not using anything directly from the `age` data.frame, is still using it for its data source. Therefore, it is putting 20 copies of "Average=42.3" on the plot, one for each row.  It is that multiple overwriting that makes it look so bad.  `geom_text` is designed to put text on a plot where the information comes from a data.frame (which it is given, either directly or indirectly in the original `ggplot` call). `annotate` is designed for simple one-off additions like you have (it creates a `geom_text`, taking care of the data source).

If you really want to use `geom_text()`, just reset the data source:

```
ggplot(age, aes(age)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(40,45,1)) +
  stat_bin(binwidth=1, color="black", fill="blue") +
  geom_text(aes(41, 5.2, 
            label=paste("Average = ", round(mean(age$age),1))), size=12,
            data = data.frame()) +
  annotate("text", x=41, y=4.5, 
           label=paste("Average = ", round(mean(age$age),1)), size=12)
```

[image]

Comment: Good to understand how `geom_text()` works. Thanks for your help Brian.

Comment: +1 Brian, an example of a well written & illustrated answer and useful tip re `annotate()`.

Comment: shouldn't it be `mean(age$age)` for `geom_text` since you reset the data?

Comment: @colinfang You are correct. Thank you for the catch. Answer has been updated.

Comment: Another easy fix for this is to use the arguement `check_overlap = TRUE` within `geom_text`

Answer (score 26):

### Try `geom_text(..., check_overlap = TRUE)`*

From the docs `?geom_text`, `check_overlap` says:

> If TRUE, text that overlaps previous text in the same layer will not be plotted.

```
library(ggplot2)
age = structure(list(age = c(41L, 40L, 43L, 44L, 40L, 42L, 44L, 45L, 
                             44L, 41L, 43L, 40L, 43L, 43L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 43L, 41L)), 
                .Names = "age", row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(age, aes(age)) + 
  geom_histogram() +
  stat_bin(binwidth=1) +
  geom_text(aes(41, 5.2, label=paste("Average = ", round(mean(age),1))), 
            size=12, 
            check_overlap = TRUE)
```

*<sub>This is essentially the answer that Dave Gruenewald posted in a comment to Brian's excellent answer. I'm just trying to make that answer more visible!</sub>