# ggplot: text printed by geom_text is not clear

Tags: r, ggplot2

The text printed using geom_text is not very clear. How can I make it more clear?

```
data = data.frame(rnorm(1000))
colnames(data) = "numOfX"
m <- ggplot(data, aes(x=numOfX))
m + geom_histogram(colour = "blue", fill = "white", binwidth = 0.5) +
  annotate("segment", x=10,xend=10,y=20,yend=0,arrow=arrow(), color="blue") +
  geom_text(aes(10, 30, label="Observed \n value"), color = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [ggplot2: Is there a fix for jagged, poor-quality text produced by geom_text()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952832/ggplot2-is-there-a-fix-for-jagged-poor-quality-text-produced-by-geom-text)

Comment: An easy fix for this is to use the argument `check_overlap = TRUE` within `geom_text`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use `annotate` for the text as well as the arrow:

```
m + geom_histogram(colour = "blue", fill = "white", binwidth = 0.5) +
  annotate("segment", x=10,xend=10,y=20,yend=0,arrow=arrow(), color="blue") +
  annotate("text", x=10, y=30, label="Observed \n value", color = "blue")
```

[image]

---

The reason is that `geom_text` overplots the text for each row of data in the data frame, whereas `annotate` plots the text only once. It is this overplotting that causes the bold, pixellated text.

<strike>I am sure this question was answered recently. I'll try to find a reference:</strike>
A similar question was asked recently:

- [ggplot2: Is there a fix for jagged, poor-quality text produced by geom_text()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952832/ggplot2-is-there-a-fix-for-jagged-poor-quality-text-produced-by-geom-text)
- [How to nicely annotate a ggplot2 (manual)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409357/how-to-nicely-annotate-a-ggplot2-manual/9081281#9081281)

Comment: So in the case, we use a vector of labels in different positions we should use `geom_text` and this will not have the blurry effect it has with only one label, right?

Comment: It's odd that overplotting with exact coordinates should lead to fuziness though

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on Dave Gruenewald's comment, `geom_text` now has the `check_overlap` option. See the [tidyverse reference](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_text.html):

> `check_overlap` -- If `TRUE`, text that overlaps previous text in the same layer will not be plotted. `check_overlap` happens at draw time and in the order of the data. Therefore data should be arranged by the label column before calling `geom_text()`. Note that this argument is not supported by `geom_label()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
data = data.frame(rnorm(1000))
colnames(data) = "numOfX"
m <- ggplot(data, aes(x=numOfX))
m + geom_histogram(colour = "blue",
                   fill = "white",
                   binwidth = 0.5) +
  annotate("segment",
           x = 10, xend = 10,
           y = 20, yend = 0,
           arrow = arrow(), color="blue") +
  geom_text(aes(10, 30, label="Observed \n value"),
            color = "blue", check_overlap = T)
```

[image]