# Use argument place holder within ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, magrittr

I am trying to use an argument place holder `.` within a `ggplot()`. But it doesn't work for some reason I am not entirely sure of.

What I am doing is this (using the sample data from `ggplot2`/the `tidyverse`):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

corr_eqn <- function(x, y, digits = 2) {
  corr_coef <-
    round(cor(x, y, use = "pairwise.complete.obs"), digits = digits)
  paste("r = ", corr_coef)
}


economics %>%
  filter(date >= "1990-11-01") %>%
  ggplot(aes(pop, unemploy)) +  
  geom_point()+
  annotate(geom = "text", x=-Inf, y=Inf, hjust=0, vjust=1,
           label = economics[economics$date>="1990-11-01",] %$% corr_eqn(pop, unemploy))
```

However, I want to reduce the command behind label to `label = . %$% corr_eqn(pop, unemploy)`. I.e. I do not want to call `economics[economics$date>="1990-11-01",]` again as I have already filtered for this:

```
economics %>%
  filter(date >= "1990-11-01") %>%
  ggplot(aes(pop, unemploy)) +  
  geom_point()+
  annotate(geom = "text", x=-Inf, y=Inf, hjust=0, vjust=1,
           label = . %$% corr_eqn(pop, unemploy))
```

However, it doesn't work with the argument place holder `.`. What should I do instead?

Plus, if it would be possible to nat having to list `pop` and `unemploy` as seperate arguments in the `corr_eqn` fn again, this would be also amazing.

Comment: Please add some example data.

Comment: sry, should have made this clear. `economics` is example data from the tidyverse/ggplot2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `annotate` is not within the pipe, so `.` has no meaning there. The `+` operator in ggplot does not have the same function as the `%>%` in magrittr; in your code the pipe effectively stops at the call to `ggplot()`. The `+` operator will allow the next function to add various elements to the plot, but it won't in general allow you to access the data that was fed to the `ggplot()` call in the way you would with the `%>%` operator.

On the other hand, if you use `geom_text` instead of `annotate`, these problems vanish because you are accessing the variables in your subsetted data directly:

```
economics %>%
  filter(date >= "1990-11-01") %>%
  ggplot(aes(pop, unemploy)) +  
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(aes(x = min(pop), y = max(unemploy), label = corr_eqn(pop, unemploy)), 
            hjust = 0, vjust = 1, size = 6)
```

[image]

Comment: an issue with this is that the text is written for each row of the data, hence it is a bit blurry. If using geom_text compare the text to using a dataframe with one row: `textDat = with(economics[economics$date >= "1990-11-01", ],                data.frame(x=min(pop),y=max(unemploy))); lbl = with(economics[economics$date >= "1990-11-01", ],corr_eqn(pop, unemploy))` then plot `plt +   geom_text(data=textDat, aes(x,y, label=lbl), hjust = 0, vjust = 3, size = 6)` (where plt if your plot).  This is why annotate is the better tool here.

Comment: seems oyu can use `, check_overlap = TRUE` now -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618392/ggplot-text-printed-by-geom-text-is-not-clear#comment80056059_11618392

Comment: @user20650 yes, you're right on both counts. The previous method I used to solve this problem was to add an `alpha = c(1, rep(0, length(var) - 1)` argument to the aesthetic mapping and `+ scale_alpha_identity()` to the plot, but `check_overlap` is a lot easier to use.