# Align geom_text to a geom_vline in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used `vjust` as workaround and elaborate an 
acceptable distance by try and error. But this is sometimes very time consuming and changes
with the font size and the axis scale.

**Is there a better method to align the text in the example automatic?**

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg))+
geom_point()+
theme_bw() +
  geom_vline(xintercept=200, colour="grey") +
  geom_text(aes(x=200, label="the strong cars", y=20), colour="blue", angle=90, vjust = 1.2, text=element_text(size=11))+
  geom_text(aes(x=200, label="the weak cars", y=20), colour="red", angle=90, vjust = -1, text=element_text(size=11))

ggsave(filename="geomline.png", width=5.5, height=2*3, dpi=300)
```

[image]

Comment: how do you want the alignment to be? vjust=0 and vjust=1 seem to do what they're supposed to, values outside this range are always more excentric.

Comment: I want that the computer looks the fontsize up and places the textbox in the correct distance. So the user will not have to play around with the vjust values.

Comment: I think positioning labels automagically is going to be hard, even if the plot is always going to be a simple one. Have you looked at the [`directlabels`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/directlabels/index.html) package?

Comment: I think directlabels goes in the right direction. But I found no way to annotate lines like in the example above.

Answer (score 49):

Another solution for the case of one line labels would be to add a line break before/after and keep the default vjust=0.5.

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_vline(xintercept=200, colour="grey") +
  geom_text(aes(x=200, label="\nthe strong cars", y=20), colour="blue", angle=90, text=element_text(size=11)) +
  geom_text(aes(x=200, label="the weak cars\n", y=20), colour="red", angle=90, text=element_text(size=11))
```

Comment: Easy and effective. I like that!

Comment: Also, to avoid rendering multiple copies, `annotate` should be used instead of `geom_text`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952832/ggplot2-is-there-a-fix-for-jagged-poor-quality-text-produced-by-geom-text

Comment: @Valentas if `annotate` does the same thing but better, it would be great to update the answer to use it

Answer (score 4):

Another option could be using the `geom_textvline` function from the great [geomtextpath](https://github.com/AllanCameron/geomtextpath) package. This can actually combine the functions `geom_text` and `geom_vline`. This package has some create function to create curved, straight automatic text annotations. Check this [link](https://allancameron.github.io/geomtextpath/) for some extra examples. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(geomtextpath)
# Using geom_textvline
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_textvline(label = "the strong cars", xintercept = 200, vjust = 1.3) +
  geom_textvline(label="the weak cars", xintercept = 200, vjust = -0.7) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

```r
# Using geom_textabline with slope
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_textabline(slope = 0.05, label = "the strong cars", intercept = 10, vjust = 1.3) +
  geom_textabline(slope = 0.05, label="the weak cars", intercept = 10, vjust = -0.7) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: in this particular example (set by the OP), this will draw two lines one above the other, which can create funny and not always desired effects.

Comment: More importantly, however, it doesn't remove the undesired manual vjust which this question is about