# R, ggplot, loop, for multiple panels

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, panels

Hey I am trying to do `ggplot` looping through 4 different cases, I have a data with 5 variables, I would like to plot out all points, regression lines, and add `y=ax+b`, and `r^2` in the plots. All are plotted in a 4 panels plots. I use `print(do.call(grid.arrange,plot)` in the end, it will generate 4 panels in same plot

[image]

If I comment out this line, it generates:

[image]

As you can see, the scatter plots are different. I wonder why this happens. Also, the `y=ax+b` and `r^2` look ugly, how to clean it up?

Thank you for your help

```
lm_eqn1 <- function(df,x,y){
  m <- lm(y ~ x, df);
#  eq <- substitute(italic(y) == a + b %.% italic(x)*","~~italic(r)^2~"="~r2,
#                   list(a = format(coef(m)[1], digits = 2),
#                        b = format(coef(m)[2], digits = 2),
#                        r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3)))
  eq<-  substitute(italic(y) == b %.% italic(x)+ a,list(a = format(coef(m)[1], digits = 2),b = format(coef(m)[2], digits = 2)))
  as.character(as.expression(eq));
}
lm_eqn2 <- function(df,x,y){
  m <- lm(y ~ x, df);
  eq2<- substitute(italic(r)^2~"="~r2,
                   list(r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3)))
  as.character(as.expression(eq2));
}

plot = list()
df <-    data.frame(as.vector(data[[1]]),as.vector(data[[2]]),as.vector(data[[3]]),as.vector(data[[4]]),as.vector(data[[5]]))
colnames(df) <- case
p = 1
for (k in 1:1){
  for (j in 2:5){
#    for (p in 1:4){
    x_lab <- paste(case[k]," [ug/m3]",sep=" ")
    y_lab <- paste(case[j]," [ug/m3]",sep=" ")
    x=df[,case[k]]
    y=df[,case[j]]
    print(case[k])
    print(case[j])
    plot[[p]] = ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
                geom_point(size=2,alpha = 0.3,color="red")+
                theme_bw(base_size=12, base_family = "Helvetica")+
                xlab(x_lab)+
                ylab(y_lab)+
                theme(aspect.ratio=1)+
                ggtitle(case[j]) +
                geom_smooth(method='lm',se = FALSE, color="black",formula = y ~ x)+
                geom_text(x=-0.0005,y=0.05,label=lm_eqn1(df,x,y),parse = TRUE)+
                geom_text(x=-0.0005,y=0.04,label=lm_eqn2(df,x,y),parse = TRUE)
#    }
     print(plot[[p]])
     p = p + 1
}
}
#print(do.call(grid.arrange,plot))
```

Comment: For the text use `annotate` instead of `geom_text` as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952832/ggplot2-is-there-a-fix-for-jagged-poor-quality-text-produced-by-geom-text/10953050#10953050)

Comment: (1) It is also probably better to rename your function from `plot` to another name as there is also a `plot` function already present in R. (2) Did you  look at `facet_wrap` from `ggplot2`?

Comment: Probably better to not use a `d` object which exists outside the ggplot2 evaluation frames. Otherwise there may not be a proper set of x and y values of values at time of evaluation.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide us with a _minimal reproducible_ example.

Comment: Seems your axes are the same in your loop. Why not just rely on the built-in `facet_wrap`?

Comment: Thanks all, I will try facet_wrap. How can I provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Search SO for "minimal reproducible example" and look for the one with lots of votes - it's not very far down the list...

Comment: I finally made my plot by assign data with two different levels (factors) and facet_grid. Thank all of your help.

here is my final code
https://gist.github.com/JiaoyanHuang/c10e51c4779885ace1ec272a135128c4

Answer (score 0):

Huang. Your script was very helpful to me. For your question, if you use 'aes_string()' instead of 'aes()' in the first line in ggplot(), it will works.

```
ggplot(df, aes_string(x=x, y=y))
```